# How to work with more than one pivot tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 4 tables.

orders - `PK(order_od)`

order_collections - `PK(order_collection_id)`, `FK(order_id)`

order_collection_products - `PK(order_collection_product_id)`, `FK(order_collection_id)`

product - `PK(product_id)`

Laravel documentation explains how to get data using just one pivot table.
So how I can get data from `product` table that related to specifyc order?
How I can use two pivot tables?

Comment: can you be more clear, about your question, do you wannt a table pivot betwen orders and product, or only you wanna have the product by the order (and viceversa).

Comment: @CarlosHerreraPlata
for example, I want to get names of all products for the specifyc order_id.
Names are stored in product table.
So I need to connect order and product tables via two pivot tables.

Comment: someting like: `product->order_collections()->first()->order->name`

Comment: @CarlosHerreraPlata could you please write classes that will be used by this statement?

Comment: you have product related to order_collection by a pivot table, and the order_collection is related to order, by one to many (i think), so, you can acces fisrt, get de order_collection  `$order_collection = product->order_collections()->fist()` and after get the order related `$order_collection->order->name`, another option is Has Many Through relation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through or do a join